# How to check SD Card Class and other specs on Windows/Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, sd-card, micro-sd-card

Is there any way to check SD card class and other specs in linux / windows? I mean read/write speed, serial, class, etc.
I amd seeking a way to determine these, specially the 'class'.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be written on the card. You can use the programs below to test.

Windows: [h2testw](http://www.heise.de/ct/Redaktion/bo/downloads/h2testw_1.4.zip)

Linux: [F3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/)

Source: [How do I check the class of a micro sd card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29601/how-do-i-check-the-class-of-a-micro-sd-card)

Comment: Please note that it is possible that the card reader be misconfigured or be a slow reader. In my case for example I have a fast card that reaches 80MB/s read in Windows but for some reason Linux would only read at 10MB/s.

Answer (score 2):

This is not information about the SD card per se, but it will show how the reader has configured itself for card access (frequency, voltage, timings)

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/mmc0/ios
```

This is for Linux. Hopefully it would have configured itself properly.